# Why can you overload __radd__ and not __rmod__ on string?

Tags: python, string, operator-overloading

In python, you can override the right (and left) addition operator (`<str> + <MyObject>`):

Let's use this dummy object for the following:

```
class Dummy(object): pass  ## dummy object
```

Here's an illustration of successfully overloading `+` operator left and right wise:

```
>>> Dummy.__add__ = lambda s, v: "LAdded: Dummy(), %s" % v
>>> Dummy() + "foo"
'LAdded: Dummy(), foo'

>>> Dummy.__radd__ = lambda s, v: "RAdded: %s, Dummy()" % v
>>> "foo" + Dummy()
'RAdded: foo, Dummy()'
```

You can also override the left string interpolation operator (`<MyObject> % <str>`):

```
>>> Dummy.__mod__ = lambda s, v: "LModded: Dummy(), %s" % v
>>> Dummy() % "foo"
'LModded: Dummy(), foo"
```

But, **you can't override the right string interpolation operator** (`<str> % <MyObject>`):

```
>>> Dummy.__rmod__ = lambda s, v: "RModded: %s, Dummy()" % v
>>> "foo" % Dummy()
'foo'
```

Our override was not called.

I need a technical answer that will acknowledge that addition `+` and interpolation `%` **are both implemented** on `str` type. But they don't seem to be implemented the same way, and as a consequence they obviously don't share the same priority.

So is there a way to take precedence on the string implementation of `%` operator ? If not, why is it possible on `+` ? Could this be considered a bug, or is there deep reason why this has to be implemented this way ? Is this by design, if yes, why ?

Many thanks for in-depth answers.

Comment: the last example throws a TypeError to me, saying `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` , where is the catch? also maybe the [first coercion rule could be relevant](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#coercion-rules)

Comment: Which version of python ? (I'm in Python 2.7.2) But anyway, this mean that you are still in string interpolation code, and not in the overridden ``__rmod__`` method.

Comment: both 2.7.8 and 3.4.2

Answer (score 3):

`__rmod__` is only called if `__mod__` returns `NotImplemented`. Your string literal `"foo"` has a perfectly functional `__mod__` method that is always capable of handling the operation. It has to, because the placholders `%s` and `%r` will work with any type of object.

`__add__`, on the other hand, only works if the other operand is another string. If it's not, the other object's `__radd__` is given a chance.

Comment: well, ``__add__`` implem exists, ``"__add__" in dir("a") -> True``, and some code will output a ``TypeError: cannot concatenate type`` instead of the standard ``TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +``. So there's perfectly functional code for ``+`` on strings that can be overridden, and there's also adhoc code for ``%``, but this code can not be overridden. Still no explanation what's the fundamental diff.

Comment: The point is, sometimes `str.__add__` gives up, which allows `Dummy.__radd__` a chance. `str.__mod__` doesn't give up, so `Dummy.__rmod__` isn't given a chance. If a non-reflected method can do the job, the reflected version on the other type is never called, because it doesn't need to be.